# Improve performance of a predicate on a large data set

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have a big data with 30907 items. Currently, im using NSPredicate to filter.
But it's very slow. Therefore, im looking for a best way to process them as faster.

This is my current code to filter 30907 items :

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                 @"((full beginswith[cd] %@) OR (full == [cd] %@) OR (search ==[cd] %@)) OR (search CONTAINS[cd] %@) OR (search beginswith[cd] %@)",matchString,matchString,matchString,strNoSpace,strNoSpace];

NSArray * arrResult = [arrSongs filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

The result is correct, but it's very slow.

Comment: there is a lot missing form this question. What does your data set look like (structure), where is it coming from, is it in a DB that you could index, is it on the phone, coming from a server, do you have any control over it etc.

Comment: Hi Simon,
My data from local files, and stored in NSMutableArray.

Comment: ... you didn't answer most of my comment. Do you have any other option than storing in a local file and parsing into a NSMutableArray ? like having them in a DB, thats a huge amount of data to be reading and sorting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try remove `(full == [cd] %@)`, this conditions are already evaluate in  full `beginswith[cd]`. In other words, strings with `(full == [cd] %@)` is a subset of `beginswith[cd]`.

The same thing happens to `(search beginswith[cd] %@)`, that are a subset of `(search CONTAINS[cd] %@)`.

So, try this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                 @"((full beginswith[cd] %@) OR (search ==[cd] %@)) OR (search CONTAINS[cd] %@)",matchString,matchString,strNoSpace];
```

Answer (score 1):

Better way of using predicate is... condition which will restrict the most data should come first in order. It will make your `predicate` work fast, as next condition will evaluate on less data.

**EDIT**:

This will not only depend on the predicate,  It also matter what data structure you are using . Every data structure also have its cost on searching, like searching in an `array` is slower then the `set`. While Iteration on `array` is faster than the `set`. Depending on the requirement we should use data structure.

Comment: Yeah, but this not apply here. Cause he is using only disjunction.

Comment: This applies the other way round: he should put all conditions ahead, which are fulfilled very often.

Comment: Thank for your answer,
Im trying to solve this problem by split my array.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the condition expression:

Have a look at it:

((full beginswith[cd] matchString) OR (full == [cd] matchString) OR (search ==[cd] matchString)) OR (search CONTAINS[cd] strNoSpace) OR (search beginswith[cd] strNoSpace)

First of all, all terms are connected with OR. you do not need parenthesis in parenthesis:

(full beginswith[cd] matchString) OR (full == [cd] matchString) OR (search ==[cd] matchString) OR (search CONTAINS[cd] strNoSpace) OR (search beginswith[cd] strNoSpace)

Second: If a string matches the stored value, it begins with it. So you do not need to check ==

(full beginswith[cd] matchString) OR (search CONTAINS[cd] strNoSpace) OR (search beginswith[cd] strNoSpace)

Third: If a string begins with a string, it contains the string: (This one can make performance worse, if you have a high number of hits. Check it out.)

(full beginswith[cd] matchString) OR (search CONTAINS[cd] strNoSpace)

Comment: You just missed just one thing, (search ==[cd] %@) is comparing with matchString, and (search CONTAINS[cd]) is comparing with strNoSpace.

Search (search ==[cd] %@) is not equivalent to (search CONTAINS[cd] %@).

Comment: Ah, okay, then you have to insert a third term, but not 5?

Comment: Exactly, see my answer ;)

Comment: Yes, I did see it. For a moment I thought that I answered twice.